# Sqlite order by clause json_extract gives malformed JSON error

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have some data in a table in sqlite database. The table has only one column with data as JSON records.

```
sqlite> .schema feeds3
CREATE TABLE feeds3 (data text NOT NULL);
```

When I am querying from the table using `json_extract` I can see the data getting fetched from the JSON path. But when I am trying to use the same json_extract in order by clause it gives me error saying malformed JSON.

```
sqlite> select json_extract(data,'$.ps') from feeds3 limit 1;
AA1227
sqlite> select * from feeds3 order by json_extract(data,'$.ps') limit 1;
Error: malformed JSON
```

The `json1` module I installed is by downloading the `json1.c` file from the below link :
https://sqlite.org/cgi/src/raw/ext/misc/json1.c?name=9799e4252b305edcbe659329eec3ca80ed85f968

and followed below steps

```
 gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib json1.c -o json1
 sqlite> .load json1
```

Sqlite version:`sqlite-snapshot-201904101324`

Comment: When building from a source tarball, just pass `--enable-json1` to `configure` to get it built in, btw. No need to compile it separately in that case.

Comment: And show some sample data for your table? I'm guessing at least one row has invalid json.

Comment: Yeah, the obvious answer is that you have bad data somewhere. If you want anything more than that you'll have to provide some examples of data that's failing.

Comment: but if it is able to extract it from the bad data, then why can't we use it in order by.

Comment: A `LIMIT` by itself just picks arbitrary rows and you got lucky. Sorting the results, on the other hand, usually requires looking at every row.